# Hook to notify eclipse workspace is loaded

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I created an eclipse application for some graphical processing. When the application is loaded for first time it is empty. User require to load some projects in application workspace to use that application.
Among these projects some contain a file with `.xyz` extension which display key value pair in tableviewer. What I need to do is to apply a hook kind mechanism which will notify when the projects/workspace is loaded and a background thread start to check `.xyz` file for synchronization with database and display any error or problem in `Eclipse Problem View`.

Also I tried `org.eclipse.ui.startup` extension point but that is to process during startup of application. What I need to do is start processing in background when the workspace is loaded.

`Workspace loading complete--notification-to-plugin--start background thread to check error/problems`

PS : I need this to be in same way as `SVN plugin` works in background when the workspace is loaded in eclipse.(Reference just for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SVN plugin uses the Team Repository APIs, but since a project can only be associated with one repository using this would conflict with the Team support.

You can use the `org.eclipse.ui.startup` extension point, but in the `earlyStartup` method you create and schedule a `UIJob` - this will not run until the UI is set up. The `UIJob` should not do the work directly, instead it should create a normal `Job` and schedule that. This seems to be essentially what the Java plugin does for the 'Initializing Java Tooling' code.